# How to use a List(Of T) as Itemssource for a WPF DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, list, datagrid

I wanted to quickly display a List(OF String) in a DataGrid (dynamically), so I thought

```
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = myList
```

would be the quick and easy way to do it, since this works great for a DataTable:

```
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = myDataTable.DefaultView
```

My DataGrid has the AutoGenerateColumns property set to 'True'.  And for the datatable this works fine, but when I assign the List(Of String) to the ItemsSource, my column name shows up as 'Length' and the displayed data are integers that are the number of characters in each String item in the List, not the actual String item.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

My test list is created like this:

```
Dim myList As New List(Of String)
  For i As Int32 = 1 To 25
  myList.Add("Item #" & i)
Next
```

The following 2 methods produce the exact same results.

Create a CollectionView:

```
Dim cv = CType(CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myList), CollectionView)
DataGrid1.ItemsSource = cv
```

Just use the List:

```
DataGrid1.ItemsSource = myList
```

Both of these methods display a single column in the DataGrid.  The column is titled 'Length' and contains integers matching the length of each string entry.

**EDIT**

Translation of answer by 'testalino' to VB:

```
DataGrid1.ItemsSource = myList.Select(Function(s) New With {.Value = s}).ToList
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your case is actually funny. You are binding elements of type string to a grid. The grid then looks for properties in type [String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) that it can display. the only property found is Length, so it creates a column named Length and displays its value.

What you need to do to avoid this is create a wrapper class for string.

Either create a class explicitly:

```
class StringWrapper
{
     string Value { get; set;}
}
```

or by using LINQ:

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>();
strings.Add("abc");
strings.Add("def");
dataGrid.ItemsSource = strings.Select(s => new { Value = s }).ToList();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are right, I was guessing that this would solve your problem since I always used CollectionViews instead instead of binding directly to the collection. I changed my answer, this should help.